# Convert wav to ogg on app engine (or in javascript?)

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, wav, html5-audio, ogg

I've built a little app engine app that lets users upload short recordings.  Some of the recordings are done in-browser with https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs, which creates wav files.  To save space, I'd like to convert those to ogg before writing them to the app engine datastore, so that I use less of my outgoing bandwidth when I play the audio recordings back to users.

How can I do this?  I googled around, and apparently there's a command line tool called oggenc that encodes to ogg -- but I'm pretty sure I can't install that (or, even if I could install it, make calls to it) on app engine.

I found a similar question at [Encode audio from getUserMedia() to a .OGG in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821919/encode-audio-from-getusermedia-to-a-ogg-in-javascript) -- this links to https://github.com/jpemartins/speex.js, a project that looks like it might eventually be able to convert from wav to ogg in javascript (which would be great), but, as far as I can tell, does not do so at the moment.  At https://github.com/jpemartins/speex.js/issues/4 the authors mentions that WAV -> ... -> OGG is not yet possible.

What else should I try?

Edit: My app engine code is written in Python, so another possibility would be to do the conversion there, with a python module that can convert wav to ogg.  I think http://pymedia.org/ can do this, but I'd have to somehow install it on app engine -- is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pymedia isn't pure python so you won't be able to use it on app engine.

You probably want to build something on Compute Engine to do this.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about Compute Engine.  If I understand correctly, I could build a service that receives WAVs, calls e.g. oggenc and spits back oggs.  That said, I would ideally find a way to do this for free and without sending so much data back and forth.  I found a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457029/converting-wav-to-any-compressed-audio-format-in-client-side-javascript -- would be great to be able to do this in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Provided it's possible to replace Matt Diamond's recorderjs with its fork, [chris-rudmin/Recorderjs](https://github.com/chris-rudmin/Recorderjs) ([demo page](https://rawgit.com/chris-rudmin/Recorderjs/master/example.html)) in AppEngine, this should be feasible. Or first encode to WAV and use [opusenc.js](https://github.com/Rillke/opusenc.js) ([demo page](https://blog.rillke.com/opusenc.js/)), which is an Emscripten port of the Opusenc tool, to convert a temporary WAV file to Ogg-Opus client side.